# LibGdx: Move camera with Keyboard visible, capture Android BACK button

Tags: android, libgdx

I have Actors that I need to move when the keyboard becomes visible (When I press a `TextField`), or they are stuck behind it. I do this by moving the camera up:

```
stage.getViewport().getCamera().position.set(stage.getWidth()/2, stage.getHeight()/3, 0);
stage.getViewport().getCamera().update();
```

This works fine. It also works fine to move it back when I touch something outside the `TextField` and call `stage.unfocusAll();`

My problem is, when I'm in a `TextField` and press Androids Back button, it hides the keyboard, but does not call the code I have inside the Inputprocessor (THIS CODE CAPTURES BACK-BUTTON ALWAYS **EXCEPT** WHEN INSIDE A TEXTFIELD AND KEYBOARD IS VISIBLE):

```
InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                if ((keycode == Input.Keys.ESCAPE) || (keycode == Input.Keys.BACK) )
                {
                    moveBack();
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

I looked around and read that it is not possible to catch the back-button when inside a `TextField`. Which leads me to my questions:

1. This must be a common scenario (moving UI to work with keyboard), how do other people do it?
2. If other people do like me (move camera), how do you handle the Android back-button?

EDIT: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880337/libgdx-how-to-catch-a-backbutton-inside-a-textfield-with-android-keyboard-visi) captures the back-key while inside a `TextField`, however it has to be done in the Android Launcher, so I can't reach the elements I need to reach. I also overwrites all other calls to the BACK-button from inside the LibGdx project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with the help of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880337/libgdx-how-to-catch-a-backbutton-inside-a-textfield-with-android-keyboard-visi) I got a solution working, but it's not very pretty.

Basically I rewrite my GDX Launcher class, and use the following code as the layout:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {


                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        game.setMoveBack(true);               }

                }
                return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
            }
        };
```

Then, in the render-method of my MainScreen (Screen that all other Screens inherit from), inside the render-method I call:

```
if(game.isMoveBack()){
            stage.getViewport().getCamera().position.set(stage.getWidth()/2, stage.getHeight()/2, 0);
            stage.getViewport().getCamera().update();
            game.setMoveBack(false);
        }
```

If anyone has an easier way to do this please post and Ill accept that as an answer, but for now, this works if anyone finds themselves where I am :)